# VBA Excel autofiltermode = false not turning off autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Have used `activesheet.autofiltermode = false` and

```
dim Myworksheet as worksheet
Myworksheet.autofiltermode = false
```

Neither removed autofilter I've use `Myworksheet.ShowAllData` beforehand as well.
Using Office 2013 Professional Plus

Comment: Is the filter part of a Table, or a regular range?

Comment: thanks that question helped me solve it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a table you need different syntax:

```
activesheet.listobjects(1).Autofilter.showalldata
```

to clear the filter, or:

```
activesheet.listobjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False
```

if you don't want the dropdowns visible at all.

Comment: Works actually arrived at solution when you asked about the table Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This *finally* helped me figure out how to ensure that an Excel table's AutoFilter is on and showing all data. My final code is this:

```
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter Then
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Else
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = True
End If
```